# How to write a regex that would ignore what would otherwise be a nested capture?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that take these:

```
 class bob
 {
       ...
 }

 class joe
 {
       {
            ...
       }
 }

 class tim
 {
       {
            ...
       }
       {
            ...
       }
 }
```

And output (white space reduced for simplicity)

```
 [0]bob
 [1] ... 

 [0]joe
 [1] { ... }

 [0]tim
 [1] { ... } { ... }
```

I've tried `class[\s]+([\w]+)[\s]*{([^}]*)}` but that (understandably) stops at the first '}'.

I've also tried `class[\s]+([\w]+)[\s]*{(.*)}` but that greedily grabs everything until the last '}'.

At the moment, I don't care what is within the outer parentheses - only that I grab it all.

As an added bit of 'fun', I'd rather not bank on there being new lines (or any specific white space outside of class[\s] - so class bob{}class joe{} would [theoretically] be a valid input string).

And no, I'm not making a full or true tokenizer/parser, just my own code visualizer (if I ever finish this side project - that is).

Comment: Do you need to handle more than one level of nested braces?

Comment: @Flimzy Yeah.  Edited to fix it.

Comment: @KendallFrey I might end up with any number of nested braces.

Comment: Are you sure you want a regex? Because this is quite complex (and won't be portable to other languages). A proper parser is just simply better. Especially if you're worried about braces in strings or comments that should be ignored, etc.

Comment: @KendallFrey If it becomes a complicated mess for just the "grab all classes and their contents", then yeah, I'll switch to making a parser.  Though what do you mean by "portable to other languages"?

Comment: The 'advanced' features of regex are largely implementation-dependent, and so a regex that could do this in .NET wouldn't work in JavaScript and Python, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use balancing groups:

```
class\s*([^{]+?)\s*\{(  # Match the class and the first '{'
    (?:                 
        [^{}]           # Match all non-braces
        |
        (?<open>\{)     # Match '{', and capture into 'open'
        |
        (?<-open>\})    # Match '}', and delete the 'open' capture
    )+
    (?(open)(?!))       # Fails if 'open' stack isn't empty
)\}
```

If you put in the comments and the indent, be sure to have the `RegexOptions.IgnoreWhitespace` flag.

Comment: Does it handle class A { const string multiline=@"} class Fake { ... }"; }

Comment: @Codism It could handle it if you modify it. Nothing about something like that was mentioned, so I didn't go that far. Plus I'm not supposed to know all the edge cases the OP could have, my regex should be able to guide them in the right direction.

Comment: the right direction should be not using regular expression. No offense but that's my first thought when I see an answer like this.

Comment: @Codism Well, you can have your own opinions, I have mine. If you believe you have a better solution, you can post it as an answer you know?

Comment: I have to admit that yours is a "good enough" solution in practice and I just wanted to draw some attention to the edge cases;-)

Comment: @Codism Hadn't even though of that edge case.  Though I will repeat, I don't intend to make a true parser (just enough to squeak by with "I've got this bit as text and this bit as text").  Darn you C for setting the precedent for descendant languages that curly braces are the universal code block signifier!

Comment: @Jerry This does answer my question as asked (not your fault I missed an edge case - and likely more than one) and I was trying to wrap my head around balancing groups after I started looking into this.

Comment: @Tory I still don't fully get balancing groups myself, and not being all that familiar with C# doesn't help either =P I hope you can find the solution you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, regular expressions cannot handle recursion. As a consequence, you cannot write a truly regular expression that matches the number of closing parentheses/curly braces/... with the number of opening ones. This means your problem cannot be solved with regular expressions.

That being said, most regex libraries have a solution for this (making them not strictly regular.) Balancing groups is one approach, as Jerry writes. PERL regular expressions have [recursive patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php):

```
class([^{}]*\{[^{}]*(?1)*[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)
```

(?1) is a recursion on the first subpattern.